# MongoDB - Calculate daily (inter-day) difference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is how my original data looks like. Basically it is an inventory that updates their quantities every day, so fields with the same name refers to the same item cathegory but in different time points:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
    "name" : "Laser Sable", 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"),
    "units": 10,
    "price": 100
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
    "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
    "units": 3,
    "price": 50
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
    "name" : "Laser Sable", 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"),
    "units": 7
    "price": 100
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
    "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
    "units": 1,
    "price": 50
}
```

After doing a `aggregation $group` query, I have a set of data like this

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : NumberInt(29), 
        "month" : NumberInt(12), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }, 
    "things" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
            "name" : "Laser Sable", 
            "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"),
            "units": 10
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
            "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
            "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
            "units": 3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : NumberInt(28), 
        "month" : NumberInt(12), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }, 
    "things" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
            "name" : "Laser Sable", 
            "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"),
            "units": 7
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
            "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
            "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
            "units": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I grouped the items according to the day the data was taken. I would like to have a way to calculate the daily difference on each item. That would mean to have a new field "difference", that would subtract current units from yesterday's units. I have been trying to accomplish that in the `aggregation framework`, but I'm struggling to find the way to refer to, f.ex: "units when name is the same and date is the same -1" Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The expected output would be something like this:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "day" : NumberInt(29), 
    "month" : NumberInt(12), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015)
}, 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
        "name" : "Laser Sable", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"),
        "units": 10,
        "daily difference":3
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
        "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
        "units": 3,
        "daily difference":2
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output? If you're trying to do what I think you're trying todo, it wont be possible in a single query.

Comment: I just edited the question to give the expected output. What I want is to keep track of the inventory difference each day, so I thought to compute the daily difference each day and then make a sumatory of the "daily differences".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to do it with just an aggregation query, but with 6 steps, it may not be the most optimal way but it works. Here comes my little monster:

```
db.stuff.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
// Stage 1
{
  $project: { 
      "_id" : 1, 
      "units" : 1, 
      "price" : 1, 
      "name" : 1, 
      "dayyear" : [
          {
              "$dayOfYear" : "$datetime"
          }, 
          {
              "$multiply" : [
                  {
                      "$add" : [
                          {
                              "$dayOfYear" : "$datetime"
                          }, 
                          1
                      ]
                  }, 
                  -1
              ]
          }
      ], 
      "datetime" : 1
  }
},

// Stage 2
{
  $unwind: "$dayyear"
},

// Stage 3
{
  $project: { 
      "_id" : 1, 
      "difference" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              {
                  "$cond" : {
                      "if" : {
                          "$lt" : [
                              "$dayyear", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      "then" : 1, 
                      "else" : -1
                  }
              }, 
              "$units"
          ]
      }, 
      "units" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              {
                  "$cond" : {
                      "if" : {
                          "$lt" : [
                              "$dayyear", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      "then" : 1, 
                      "else" : -1
                  }
              }, 
              "$units"
          ]
      }, 
      "price" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              {
                  "$cond" : {
                      "if" : {
                          "$lt" : [
                              "$dayyear", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      "then" : 1, 
                      "else" : -1
                  }
              }, 
              "$price"
          ]
      }, 
      "price difference" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              {
                  "$cond" : {
                      "if" : {
                          "$lt" : [
                              "$dayyear", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      "then" : -1, 
                      "else" : 1
                  }
              }, 
              "$price"
          ]
      }, 
      "name" : 1, 
      "dayyear" : {
          "$cond" : {
              "if" : {
                  "$eq" : [
                      {
                          "$abs" : "$dayyear"
                      }, 
                      366
                  ]
              }, 
              "then" : 1, 
              "else" : {
                  "$abs" : "$dayyear"
              }
          }
      }, 
      "year" : {
          "$cond" : {
              "if" : {
                  "$eq" : [
                      {
                          "$abs" : "$dayyear"
                      }, 
                      366
                  ]
              }, 
              "then" : {
                  "$add" : [
                      {
                          "$year" : "$datetime"
                      }, 
                      1
                  ]
              }, 
              "else" : {
                  "$year" : "$datetime"
              }
          }
      }, 
      "datetime" : 1
  }
},

// Stage 4
{
  $group: { 
      "_id" : {
          "dayyear" : "$dayyear", 
          "year" : "$year", 
          "name" : "$name"
      }, 
      "difference" : {
          "$push" : "$difference"
      }, 
      "price difference" : {
          "$push" : "$price difference"
      }, 
      "things" : {
          "$push" : "$$ROOT"
      }
  }
},


// Stage 5
{
  $project: { 
      "_id" : {
          "$arrayElemAt" : [
              "$things._id", 
              0
          ]
      }, 
      "dayyear" : "$_id.dayyear", 
      "year" : "$_id.year", 
      "name" : "$_id.name", 
      "datetime" : "$things.datetime", 
      "difference" : {
          "$cond" : {
              "if" : {
                  "$eq" : [
                      {
                          "$size" : [
                              "$difference"
                          ]
                      }, 
                      2
                  ]
              }, 
              "then" : {
                  "$add" : [
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$difference", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$difference", 
                              1
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }, 
              "else" : 0
          }
      }, 
      "price difference" : {
          "$cond" : {
              "if" : {
                  "$eq" : [
                      {
                          "$size" : [
                              "$price difference"
                          ]
                      }, 
                      2
                  ]
              }, 
              "then" : {
                  "$add" : [
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$price difference", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$price difference", 
                              1
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }, 
              "else" : 0
          }
      }, 
      "units" : {
          "$cond" : {
              "if" : {
                  "$lt" : [
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$things.units", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      0
                  ]
              }, 
              "then" : {
                  "$abs" : {
                      "$arrayElemAt" : [
                          "$things.units", 
                          0
                      ]
                  }
              }, 
              "else" : {
                  "$abs" : {
                      "$arrayElemAt" : [
                          "$things.units", 
                          1
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }, 
      "price" : {
          "$cond" : {
              "if" : {
                  "$lt" : [
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$things.price", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      0
                  ]
              }, 
              "then" : {
                  "$abs" : {
                      "$arrayElemAt" : [
                          "$things.price", 
                          0
                      ]
                  }
              }, 
              "else" : {
                  "$abs" : {
                      "$arrayElemAt" : [
                          "$things.price", 
                          1
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
},

// Stage 6
{
  $project: { 
      "_id" : 1, 
      "name" : 1, 
      "units" : 1, 
      "price" : 1, 
      "dayyear" : 1, 
      "year" : 1, 
      "datetime" : {
          "$ifNull" : [
              {
                  "$cond" : {
                      "if" : {
                          "$eq" : [
                              {
                                  "$dayOfYear" : {
                                      "$arrayElemAt" : [
                                          "$datetime", 
                                          0
                                      ]
                                  }
                              }, 
                              "$dayyear"
                          ]
                      }, 
                      "then" : {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$datetime", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      "else" : {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$datetime", 
                              1
                          ]
                      }
                  }
              }, 
              {
                  "$add" : [
                      {
                          "$arrayElemAt" : [
                              "$datetime", 
                              0
                          ]
                      }, 
                      86400000
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }, 
      "difference" : 1, 
      "total difference" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              "$price", 
              "$difference"
          ]
      }, 
      "price difference" : 1, 
      "inventory adjust for price change" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              "$price difference", 
              "$units"
          ]
      }, 
      "unitsprice" : {
          "$multiply" : [
              "$price", 
              "$units"
          ]
      }
  }
},
]
);
```

Basically what I did is:

> Stage 1: I changed the day field to an array, being the first element
>   of that field the original day, and the second, (the original day +1)
>   multiplied by -1. The reason I multiplied it is in order to be able
>   later to distinguish the "clones" from the originals.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(10), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : [
    NumberInt(363), 
    NumberInt(-364)
    ]
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(3), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : [
    NumberInt(363), 
    NumberInt(-364)
    ]
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(7), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : [
    NumberInt(362), 
    NumberInt(-363)
    ]
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(1), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : [
    NumberInt(362), 
    NumberInt(-363)
    ]
}
```

> Stage 2: I unwinded using the day variable, so now each input is
>   duplicated (note all the clone are "marked" as their date is in
>   negative).

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(10), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(10), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(-364)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(3), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(3), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(-364)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(7), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(362)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(7), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(-363)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(1), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(362)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(1), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(-363)
}
```

> Stage 3: Here I combine two actions. First I multiply by -1 the units and the price in the "originals" (the ones that had a positive number in "dayyear" ), and then multiply by -1 the difference in the clones (here you could also do the opposite-multiply by -1 the difference in the originals and not in the clones, it will depend how you want the difference to be computed) and then also transform all dayyears to positive (in order to be able to group by that field afterwards). Also in case the inventory I taken the last day of the year, I set conditions so the clone refers to the 1st year of the following year.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(-10), 
"price" : NumberInt(-100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
"difference" : NumberInt(-10), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(100), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(10), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
"difference" : NumberInt(10), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(-100), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(-3), 
"price" : NumberInt(-50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
"difference" : NumberInt(-3), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(50), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(3), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
"difference" : NumberInt(3), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(-50), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(-7), 
"price" : NumberInt(-100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
"difference" : NumberInt(-7), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(100), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(7), 
"price" : NumberInt(100), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
"difference" : NumberInt(7), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(-100), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(-1), 
"price" : NumberInt(-50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
"difference" : NumberInt(-1), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(50), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
"units" : NumberInt(1), 
"price" : NumberInt(50), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
"difference" : NumberInt(1), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(-50), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015)
}
```

> Stage 4: Here I group by name, year and dayyear, so now I have an array 
>   to do the price difference and another for the units difference

```
{ 
"_id" : {
    "dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015), 
    "name" : "Flying Skateboard"
}, 
"difference" : [
    NumberInt(-1)
], 
"price difference" : [
    NumberInt(50)
], 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
        "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(-1), 
        "price" : NumberInt(-50), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(-1), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(50), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }
]
}
{ 
"_id" : {
    "dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015), 
    "name" : "Laser Sable"
}, 
"difference" : [
    NumberInt(-7)
], 
"price difference" : [
    NumberInt(100)
], 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
        "name" : "Laser Sable", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(-7), 
        "price" : NumberInt(-100), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(-7), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(100), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }
]
}
{ 
"_id" : {
    "dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015), 
    "name" : "Flying Skateboard"
}, 
"difference" : [
    NumberInt(-3), 
    NumberInt(1)
], 
"price difference" : [
    NumberInt(50), 
    NumberInt(-50)
], 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
        "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(-3), 
        "price" : NumberInt(-50), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(-3), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(50), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
        "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(1), 
        "price" : NumberInt(50), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(1), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(-50), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }
]
}
{ 
"_id" : {
    "dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015), 
    "name" : "Laser Sable"
}, 
"difference" : [
    NumberInt(10)
], 
"price difference" : [
    NumberInt(-100)
], 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
        "name" : "Laser Sable", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(10), 
        "price" : NumberInt(100), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(10), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(-100), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }
]
}
{ 
"_id" : {
    "dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015), 
    "name" : "Flying Skateboard"
}, 
"difference" : [
    NumberInt(3)
], 
"price difference" : [
    NumberInt(-50)
], 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
        "name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(3), 
        "price" : NumberInt(50), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(3), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(-50), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }
]
}
{ 
"_id" : {
    "dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2015), 
    "name" : "Laser Sable"
}, 
"difference" : [
    NumberInt(-10), 
    NumberInt(7)
], 
"price difference" : [
    NumberInt(100), 
    NumberInt(-100)
], 
"things" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
        "name" : "Laser Sable", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(-10), 
        "price" : NumberInt(-100), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(-10), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(100), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
        "name" : "Laser Sable", 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
        "units" : NumberInt(7), 
        "price" : NumberInt(100), 
        "dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
        "difference" : NumberInt(7), 
        "price difference" : NumberInt(-100), 
        "year" : NumberInt(2015)
    }
]
}
```

> Stage 5: I add the elements in the "difference" array so I get the
>   units inter-day difference in each item. I also choose from the others
>   arrays that were created always the negative terms (as they were the
>   marked as "originals"), so then I can have the original price and
>   total units of each day for each item

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea7"), 
"difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : [
    ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000")
], 
"units" : NumberInt(1), 
"price" : NumberInt(50)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea6"), 
"difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(362), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : [
    ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000")
], 
"units" : NumberInt(7), 
"price" : NumberInt(100)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"difference" : NumberInt(-2), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : [
    ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000"), 
    ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.912+0000")
], 
"units" : NumberInt(3), 
"price" : NumberInt(50)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"difference" : NumberInt(-3), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(363), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : [
    ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000"), 
    ISODate("2015-12-28T13:28:50.823+0000")
], 
"units" : NumberInt(10), 
"price" : NumberInt(100)
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea5"), 
"difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015), 
"name" : "Flying Skateboard", 
"datetime" : [
    ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.912+0000")
], 
"units" : null, 
"price" : null
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56828a929da4bc16eb534ea4"), 
"difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"price difference" : NumberInt(0), 
"dayyear" : NumberInt(364), 
"year" : NumberInt(2015), 
"name" : "Laser Sable", 
"datetime" : [
    ISODate("2015-12-29T13:28:50.823+0000")
], 
"units" : null, 
"price" : null
}
```

> Finally, in order to keep the correct ISODate for each element, I
>   check which element of the array is equivalent to the "dayyear" field.
>   In case there is just one element in the array and it is not equal to
>   "dayyear", it will sum one day to the ISODate element (note that the
>   "real date" will always be either one day or the following.

After this 6 steps now it is ready to be grouped by month, year or name.
Note that always the last elements will be the remaining "clones", with the date of tomorrow, but as all their fields are 0 or null, they don't influence aggregation measures (as total sales, etc.) But you have to take care when making averages, as they will affect them. Hope that helps!